# How to bind an inline anonymous function?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to `bind` (ie `bind(this)`) the inline anonymous callback function to the `object`
How can it be done?

Simplified example:

```
var object = {

  property: function() {

    this.id = 'abc'; // 'this' binds to the object

    aFunctionWithCallback(this.id, function(data) {
      console.log(this); // null
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: How do you normally do it? Have you tried it?

Comment: Well, `functionName.bind(this)(arg)` but I hadn't tried it in such a case & didn't find the info, hence the question :)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The same way you always use `bind`.

Get a reference to the function (such as is returned by a function expression), and call the `bind` method on it.

```
aFunctionWithCallback(this.id, function(data) {
  console.log(this);
}.bind(this));
```

---

JS had added a new feature since this answer was written: [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

They bind `this` lexically instead of determining its value based on how the function is called so you can simply drop one into this code:

```
aFunctionWithCallback(this.id, (data) => {
  console.log(this);
});
```

Comment: "console.log(this); // null" ... `this` can never be `null`.

Comment: plalx: That is what the console logged. Please note that above was a seriously simplified example.  
Quentin: Many thanks indeed :)

Comment: Alternative would be to use a closure and transpiler.

Comment: @CoreyAlix — `bind` is a built-in function which uses a closure. I don't see how a transpiler would be relevant.

Comment: @Quentin - instead of function(data) {...}.bind(this) use data => {}.  I guess I meant lambda?
[typescript example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=var%20x%20%3D%20y%20%3D%3E%20this.name%20%2B%20y%3B)

Comment: @CoreyAlix — They are called *arrow functions*, and you could use one today, but in 2014 they were rather bleeding edge.

Comment: I don't think this answer is right. "this" is bound only after the anonymous function definition is complete, so the new binding cannot be used inside the anonymous function, which I think was wanted. The value of "this" is window instead of either the anonymous function or the variable to which it is assigned, if any.

Comment: @DavidSpector — Look at the context of the question. The code in this answer is a modification of code which appears **inside a method**. `this` is supposed to be the object on which that method is attached, not the anonymous function on which `bind` is called.

Comment: Both instances of "this" are inside the anonymous function, which is then a property of an object. The instances are not outside.

Comment: @DavidSpector — Oh. There are **two** anonymous functions. I thought you were talking about the other one. When `object.property()` is called, `this` is `object`, not `window`. That's `this` 101.

Comment: Wow, this is insane. I've doing javascript for such a long time and it's rare to see something mind-blowing. Thanks for the answer.