# $emit does not work from an anonymous function

Tags: vue.js, anonymous-function

In the mounted hook I have the following anonymous function:

```js
window.onkeydown = function(evt) {
  evt = evt || window.event;

  var isEscape = false;

  if ("key" in evt) {
     isEscape = evt.key === "Escape" || evt.key === "Esc";
  } else {
    isEscape = evt.keyCode === 27;
  }

  if (isEscape) {
    this.$emit("close");
  }
};
```

However, when hitting the `esc` button, I get the following error:

> app.js:2033 Uncaught TypeError: this.$emit is not a function
>       at window.onkeydown (app.js:2033)

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function keyword creates a new context for this. To use this keyword inside a function, you can either [bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467746/how-to-bind-an-inline-anonymous-function) it, assign it to another variable such as `var self = this` or use an arrow function which does not create a new context.

```
window.onkeydown = evt => 
{ 
  evt = evt || window.event;
  var isEscape = false;
  if ("key" in evt) {
    isEscape = evt.key === "Escape" || evt.key === "Esc";
  } else {
    isEscape = evt.keyCode === 27;
  }

  if (isEscape) {
    this.$emit("close");
  }
};
```